# Description of all the attributes that are displayed in respose after opening REST based Ambari Services

Tags: hadoop, ambari, biginsights

Is there any link or reference where descriptions of all the attributes for Ambari Services are available?

I see many attributes like "component_name", "desired_stack_id", "stale_configs", "upgrade_state" and many others when I check the response from `http://.....:8080/api/v1/clusters/....../hosts/...../host_components/HIVE_SERVER`. I want to understand the significance of all these attributes.

```
"cluster_name": "",
"component_name": "HIVE_SERVER",
"desired_stack_id": "",
"desired_state": "STARTED",
"hdp_version": "",
"host_name": "",
"maintenance_state": "OFF",
"service_name": "HIVE",
"stack_id": "",
"stale_configs": false,
"state": "STARTED",
"upgrade_state": "NONE"
```

Comment: make post easier to read; deduplicate

Answer (score 0):

I see useful information around this at below link:
https://github.com/apache/ambari/blob/trunk/ambari-server/docs/api/v1/index.md